Merge values of variables that are mixed: numeric and character
I have a dataset that looks like this:
dataset1;
input Variable1 Variable2;
cards;
124.3   1243
721     721
V304     .
332.9   3329
V202     .
;
run;

Is there a way to get the following?
dataset2;
input Variable1 Variable2;
cards;
124.3   1243
721     721
V304    V304
332.9   3329
V202    V202
;
run;

In other words I need to replace missing values in Variable2 with values in Variable1.
I tried to use "coalesce" but it doesn't work maybe because values are both numeric and character. Overall the two variables (Variable1 and Variable2) are char.
Thank you very much.

Are you saying that Variable1 and Variable2 are both defined as character in the data? Or is Variable1 character and Variable2 numeric?

Hi Stu. Yes they are both character variables after proc contents.

Use coalescec to put them together. If variable2 is already missing then you can skip the if statement.
data want;
    set dataset1;
    
    if(strip(variable2) = '.') then variable2 = '';

    variable2 = coalescec(variable2, variable1);
run;

